# PHP ajax date parsing error

Tags: php, json, yii

I am sending data in controller containing dates having format described below
Sun Mar 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000
The Code in my controller is

```
public function actionSaveajaxevent() {

    if (isset($_POST['Event']) && isset($_POST['datetime']) && isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['end'])) {
        $start = $_POST['start'];
        $end = $_POST['end'];
        $title = $_POST['Event']['title'];

        if ($model->save()) {
            $array = ['title' => $model->title, 'start' => $start, 'end' => $end];
            echo json_encode($array);
        }
    } else {
        print_r($model->getErrors());
    }
}
```

and i want to get title , start and end in my view . the jquery function in view is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#w1').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var postData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                data: postData,
                url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('site/saveajaxevent'); ?>',
                success: function (data) {
                    var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                  console.log(response.title);
                    return false;
                },
            });
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

below is error in my console

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

return JSON.parse( data + "" );

thanks in advance

Comment: console.log data before the parse to see what it looks like.

Comment: Just a sidenote... you can use `isset` with multiple variables, to check them all at once e.g. `isset($_POST['Event'], $_POST['datetime'],...)`. With that said, where does the method get `$model` from? Could you mean `$this->model`? I'm betting the JSON is messed up due to PHP showing an error about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add check the response coming from server in your Ajax code, is it correct or not:

```
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#w1').submit(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var postData = $(this).serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: postData,
                            url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('site/saveajaxevent'); ?>',
                            success: function (data) {

                              alert(data);  //before parse the JSON first alert the response

                              //var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                              //console.log(response.title);
                              return false;
                            },
                        });
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
```